# SQL looking for all values of a column in another table

Tags: sql, compare

Ok, I have a table where there are student IDs and courses they take.
such as

```
00001 CS-543
00001 CS-145
00002 HIST-123
... etc.
```

and I have a column of some course ids; lets call this B,

```
CS-123
... etc.
```

I want to search for all students who take all the courses in B. how can i write a query for this?

Comment: YOu haven't defined any relationship between table A and B. How are they connected to each other. And try to stop with "OK", and "Lets call this", and write a clearer question, please.

Comment: The operator you require is 'relational division', Google it e.g. http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.StudentID
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON A.CourseID = B.CourseID
GROUP BY A.StudentID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.CourseID) >= COUNT(DISTINCT B.CourseID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT FROM A WHERE STUDENT NOT IN
(
  SELECT STUDENT FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT FROM A) AS ALLSTUDENTS 
     CROSS JOIN B  
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT * FROM A
  ) AS INCOMPLETE
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.CourseID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM A)
```

This will give you all records in B that appear in A